# While loop without a counter in SQL - help

Tags: sql-server, printing, while-loop

I am running the following code. The code does not loop through all the records that are there in the @result. What is the correct syntax. Do I *have* to use counter in this case? I want it to be flexible so it print all values that are there in the variable.

```
declare @result varchar(1000)
select @result = item from items

while @result != ''
begin
print @result
end
```

---

```
Select item from items
```

result in this query

[image]

What I am getting from print is an endless loop that I have to manually stop and it prints this ...

```
small bed
small bed
small bed
small bed
```

What is decent way to print all values in the variable. I am talking about text data only, not numbers.

Comment: Also, to add, technically doing "select item from items" is precisely what you're looking for, an output of the items table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cursor to iterate over all of the data returned from your query.

```
declare a_cursor cursor for select Item from Items
declare @Item varchar(1000)

open a_cursor
fetch next from a_cursor into @Item
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
     print @Item
     fetch next from a_cursor into @Item
end

close a_cursor
deallocate a_cursor
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest to the OP to not even researching what a cursor is until you understand database fundamentals.

Comment: This did the job for me since I needed to format the output as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @result = ''

SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + Item from Items

PRINT @Result
```

That's all you need.  The `WHILE` loop is superfluous.

Comment: Cool, I've never selected into a variable while consuming that variable at the same time before.

Answer (score 2):

This might be difficult to explain, because it appears you're missing a fundamental understanding of the way SQL/databases work.

The code you wrote can only store a single value of the item column from the items table. Think of a `varchar(1000)` as the equivalent of a `string` in your favorite procedural language. The `select @result = ...` statement is essentially going to each row and setting @result to item, which means @result keeps getting replaced with the next value (and, upon conclusion of the statement, it's contents will be the last value in the table).

In general, you shouldn't be using loops in SQL code. That is best left for whatever front-end application needs the data. Of course, there are exceptions.

I would strongly suggest reading a primer on SQL, particularly on set-based operations vs procedural operations.

JNK's solution may give you what you're looking for in this instance, but I would question what exactly you would need that type of solution for in the first place.

Comment: I am retrieving the stored procedures that I changed and deploying it on production server.

Comment: In that case, Craig's answer will provide what you seek.